# What does summat mean here?

Tags: word-meaning

'Anyway-Harry,' said the giant, turning his back on the Dursleys, 'a very happy birthday to yeh. Got summat fer yeh here - I mighta sat on it at some point, but it'll taste all right.'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a British dialect way of pronouncing "**something**".

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/summat) gives this definition:

> Summat is a British dialect form of the word 'something'.
>
> *Are we going to write a story or summat?*

Comment: "*for whatever that's worth*", the same word is pronounced "sumfin" in the Cockney dialect.

Comment: Yorkshire is by no means the only part of the country where people say 'summat'. It's actually a contraction of _somewhat_, which used to mean the same as _something_.

Comment: @KateBunting Can you please use "somewhat" in a natural sentence where it means "something"? I've never come across that

Comment: @gotube - The use of _somewhat_ to mean _something_ is obsolete - I only mentioned it to explain the derivation of _summat_. Among various examples found by an Ngram of _somewhat is_ - "...the best painters and poets, where somewhat is left to be supplied by the spectator's and reader's imagination." (William Shenstone, 1804)